# How to parse JSON using GSON without implementing custom serializer and deserializer?

Tags: json, serialization, gson

**Sample JSON :**

```
{
    "outputs": [
        {
            "ports": {
                "1521/tcp/oracle_tnslsnr": [
                    {
                        "hostname": "172.27.64.253"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "has_attachment": 0,
            "custom_description": null,
            "plugin_output": "Nothing here",
            "hosts": null,
            "severity": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I have parsed the same using Jackson but want to do it with GSON.

Comment: Show us what you tried until now, so we can help you...

Answer (score 0):

this is one the weirdest response i have written convenience model classes to reproduce the response I hope this helps

> OutOfNamesMate

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class OutOfNamesMate {

    @SerializedName("hostname")
    private String hostname;

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public void setHostname(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }
}
```

> Port

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Port {

    @SerializedName("1521/tcp/oracle_tnslsnr")
    private ArrayList<OutOfNamesMate> outOfNamesMates;

    public ArrayList<OutOfNamesMate> getOutOfNamesMates() {
        return outOfNamesMates;
    }

    public void setOutOfNamesMates(ArrayList<OutOfNamesMate> outOfNamesMates) {
        this.outOfNamesMates = outOfNamesMates;
    }
}
```

> Output.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Output {

    @SerializedName("ports")
    private Port ports;

    @SerializedName("has_attachment")
    private String has_attachment;

    @SerializedName("custom_description")
    private String custom_description;

    @SerializedName("plugin_output")
    private String plugin_output;

    @SerializedName("hosts")
    private String hosts;

    @SerializedName("severity")
    private String severity;

    public Port getPorts() {
        return ports;
    }

    public void setPorts(Port ports) {
        this.ports = ports;
    }

    public String getHas_attachment() {
        return has_attachment;
    }

    public void setHas_attachment(String has_attachment) {
        this.has_attachment = has_attachment;
    }

    public String getCustom_description() {
        return custom_description;
    }

    public void setCustom_description(String custom_description) {
        this.custom_description = custom_description;
    }

    public String getPlugin_output() {
        return plugin_output;
    }

    public void setPlugin_output(String plugin_output) {
        this.plugin_output = plugin_output;
    }

    public String getHosts() {
        return hosts;
    }

    public void setHosts(String hosts) {
        this.hosts = hosts;
    }

    public String getSeverity() {
        return severity;
    }

    public void setSeverity(String severity) {
        this.severity = severity;
    }
}
```

> Response

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

    @SerializedName("outputs")
    private ArrayList<Output> output;

    public ArrayList<Output> getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public void setOutput(ArrayList<Output> output) {
        this.output = output;
    }
}
```

> Test Code
>   following is the test code to check if the classes are working,

you can use above model classes in your code but following code is strictly made to match your data by no means that is a standard way of generating `JSON` data, it is up to you how do you want to populate your object

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class TestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OutOfNamesMate mate = new OutOfNamesMate();
        mate.setHostname("172.27.64.253");
        ArrayList<OutOfNamesMate> mates = new ArrayList<>();
        mates.add(mate);
        Port port = new Port();
        port.setOutOfNamesMates(mates);

        Output output = new Output();
        output.setPorts(port);
        output.setHas_attachment("0");
        output.setCustom_description("");
        output.setPlugin_output("Nothing here");
        output.setHosts("");
        output.setSeverity("3");

        String result = (new Gson()).toJson(output);
        System.out.println(""+result);

    }
}
```

> Output

```
{
  "ports": {
    "1521/tcp/oracle_tnslsnr": [
      {
        "hostname": "172.27.64.253"
      }
    ]
  },
  "has_attachment": "0",
  "custom_description": "",
  "plugin_output": "Nothing here",
  "hosts": "",
  "severity": "3"
}
```

Comment: What in case the port and protocol value, which in this case is "1521/tcp/oracle_tnslsnr" Dynamic.

Comment: if "1521/tcp/oracle_tnslsnr" is dynamic then it should not be a key at all but a value, you can have key static and the values ca be dynamic you dont have to worry how it is loaded gson will take care of it